# Ionic 3 - Preventing browser close

Tags: angular, dom, ionic3

When the user tries to close the page (clicking the X button on the browser window or navigating away from the page) I need to send a message like 'Are you sure ?' and perform some actions.

I' am using Ionic 3 and this is my configuration

> cli packages: (/home/ubuntu/workspace/mHS/node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.4.0
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Node : v6.11.2
> npm  : 5.3.0 
> OS   : Linux 4.9
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : legacy
> ```

I tried different approach without succeed:

**1 - Ionic Lifecycle Hooks**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Events, LoadingController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html'
})

export class SignupPage {

....

ionViewWillUnload() {
    console.log("I'm about to unload");
  }

}
```

**2 - Host Listener**

```
import { Component, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Events, LoadingController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html'})

export class SignupPage {

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
   handler(event: Event) {
    console.log('event logged')
  }

...
```

}

**3 - Inside HTML**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>{{pageTitle}}</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content onbeforeunload="myScript()">
....
</ion-content>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you show the `code`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is number 2 - Host listener; I forgot to return a boolean.
This way work perfectly.

```
export class SignupPage {

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onbeforeunload(event) {
      return this.signupCompleted;
    }
  }
  signupCompleted = false;
...
}
```